# Extract data from a pandas dataframe strings column and generate new columns based on content in it

Tags: python

I have a pandas column which has data like this :

**Title **:  New_ind

**Body **: Detection_error

*respo_URL **: [www.github.com](http://www.github.com)

**respo_status **: {color}

```
data = {'sl no': [661, 662],
        'key': ['3484', '3483'],
        'id': [13592349, 13592490],
        'Sum': ['[E-1]', '[E-1]'],
        'Desc': [
              "**Title **: New_ind\n\n**Body **: Detection_error\n\n*respo_URL **: www.github.com\n\n**respo_status **: {yellow}","**Title **: New_ind2\n\n**Body **: import_error\n\n*respo_URL **: \n\n**respo_status **: {green}"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to generate new columns where Title, Body, response_URL, etc would be column names and everything after : should be the value contained in those column cells. Just to mention the items in the column are not dictionaries

Comment: @Timus They are actually not dictionary which is why I am having a problem

Comment: @Timus I have added two rows of the data here, Please let me know if this is sufficient. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do that with regex but I found this with `str`-methods to be the clearest:

```py
desc_df = df["Desc"].str.split("\n\n", expand=True)
for col in desc_df.columns:
    desc_df[col] = desc_df[col].str.split(":").str[1].str.strip()
colnames = "Title", "Body", "respo_URL", "respo_status"
desc_df = desc_df.rename(columns=dict(enumerate(colnames)))
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns="Desc"), desc_df], axis=1)
```

- First split column `Desc` at `\n\n` and expand the result into a dataframe `desc_df`.
- Then split each new column at `:`, take the right side, and strip whitespace.
- Finally change the column names and concat the initial dataframe without the `Desc` column and `desc_df`.

Result for the sample:

```
   sl no   key        id    Sum     Title             Body       respo_URL  \
0    661  3484  13592349  [E-1]   New_ind  Detection_error  www.github.com   
1    662  3483  13592490  [E-1]  New_ind2     import_error                   

  respo_status  
0     {yellow}  
1      {green}
```

The following regex-version worked for the sample, but I think it's not as robust the other one:

```py
pattern = "\n\n".join(
    f"\*+{col} \*+: (?P<{col}>[^\n]*)"
    for col in ("Title", "Body", "respo_URL", "respo_status")    
)
desc_df = df["Desc"].str.extract(pattern)
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns="Desc"), desc_df], axis=1)
```